# What does it mean to pass null as an argument to createContext in React?

Tags: reactjs

I usually do this and I see many people doing the same and it works. But I really have no idea what it means to pass `null` as an argument to `createContext()`

```
const ctx = createContext(null)
```

[In the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) they mention the following:

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This default value can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them. Note: passing undefined as a Provider value does not cause consuming components to use defaultValue.

Which I honestly don't understand.

If someone could explain in simpler terms, would be much appreciated.

Comment: The text is pretty clear: if you don't pass anything, the argument value will be `undefined`, and defaultValue won't be used. If you pass `null`, which is _not_ undefined, defaultValue _will_ get used, and it will be the value `null`. Is that useful in production? No. Is that useful for, as pointed out, testing context-dependent components without setting up all the context providers as part of test setup? Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Could you please expand on why is not useful for production ? and I really don't get the last part `testing context-dependent components without setting up all the context providers as part of test setup? Absolutely.` what does it mean to `set up all the context providers`?

Comment: Unit testing 101: you test individual parts of your application in isolation. So if you have components that rely on context providers, those components should still work "on their own".  Code that uses `ctx.Provider` or `ctx.Consumer` won't error out, it just won't render those parts of your component's tree, as it should.